# ggplot2: Display per Months using Stacked Bar Chart with

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

With ggplot, I want to create an overview that shows what kind of tasks have to be done on three (agricultural) fields over the course of a year (per month). I want to use a stacked bar chart to create a chart that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ijl7.jpg): Months on the x-axis, one bar per field on the y-axis, and the different tasks that have to be performed should be indicated via four different colours.

This is the code I have come up with:

```
# required packages

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# data

df34278 <- structure(list(fieldID = c("fieldA", "fieldB", "fieldC"), January = c("task2", 
"task3", "task2"), February = c("task2", "task3", "task2"), March = c("task2", 
"task3", "task2"), April = c("task2", "task3", "task1"), May = c("task2", 
"task3", "task4"), June = c("task1", "task3", "task4"), July = c("task2", 
"task3", "task4"), August1 = c("task2", "task2", "task4"), August15 = c("task2", 
"task2", "task2"), September = c("task1", "task2", "task2"), 
    October = c("task3", "task2", "task2"), November = c("task3", 
    "task2", "task2"), December = c("task3", "task2", "task2"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

# transform to longer format and convert df34278$Task to factor

df34278_longer <- pivot_longer(df34278,
                               cols = 2:14,
                               names_to = "Month",
                               values_to = "Task")

df34278_longer$Task <- as.factor(df34278_longer$Task)

# create plot

plot34278 <- ggplot(df34278_longer, aes(x = fieldID, y = Month, fill = Task)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  coord_flip()
  
plot34278
```

However, the result is not as intended: The tasks are not kept in the order of the months (and I also can't get the month labels right). I realise this is probably not a use of stacked bar charts as they were intended, so I am happy to hear other suggestions for drawing this kind of plot using R/ggplot2.

```
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.9
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `geom_tile()` would be more appropriate in this case. For example

```
df34278_longer <- pivot_longer(df34278,
                               cols = 2:14,
                               names_to = "Month",
                               values_to = "Task")

df34278_longer$Task <- as.factor(df34278_longer$Task)
df34278_longer$Month <- forcats::fct_inorder(df34278_longer$Month)

# create plot

ggplot(df34278_longer, aes(x = fieldID, y = Month, fill = Task)) +
  geom_tile() + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mrflick, I did not think of geom_tile(), that works just as I want it to!